# Named ranges won't work

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

Whenever I try to make a named range in Excel I keep getting an error. I believe my formula is correct:

```
=OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNTA($B$2:$B$200),1)
```

However when I press OK I keep getting the dialog screen which states Excel found a problem with my formula.
Then it highlights the following part of the formula: `$B$2,0,0,COUNTA`.

I looked through various tutorials where this formula should be correct.

Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Does your locale use semicolons `;` for the argument separators?  (Or some character other than the comma `,`)

Comment: As other posters have said - probably down to the argument separators.  
I've no idea how large your workbook is, but the OFFSET formula can cause slowdown and I'd suggest using this alternative formula:  **=$B$2:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B))**.  

Have a look at this site for further info on volatile functions: http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/

Comment: As a named range ensure you're referencing the worksheet that the formula should apply to, otherwise it will use the same sheet as the named range is used in.

**=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$200),1)**

Comment: Does the range B2:B200 contain any values when you are trying to define the range?

Answer (score 0):

One way to see this error message is if you are using the incorrect argument separators.  For example, many locale's use the semicolon `;`.

Try replacing the commas in your formula with semicolons

```
=OFFSET($B$2;0;0;COUNTA($B$2:$B$200);1)
```

or whatever your locale argument separator is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it were indeed the seperators which caused the problem: I have to use ; instead of a , - this tricked me as all of the tutorials I watched used the comma as well.